# Modify php function get_custom_logo to return random images

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm very inexperienced with coding, so to anyone who bears with me a huge thank you in advance!

Here's what I'm trying to do: I want to make my website - that's currently displaying a logo that I've picked - display **randomly** one of the images that I've uploaded as the logo every time the page reloads.

Now this would be relatively easy if the theme was coded with a header - but for logos I can't find a plugin that does that and also can't manage to add this feature from inside the theme.

This is how the wordpress theme of my website calls for a logo:

```
<?php 
        if( $show_logo && has_custom_logo() ) {
        the_custom_logo();
```

Here's the *the_custom_logo()* functions code:

```
function the_custom_logo( $blog_id = 0 ) {
         echo get_custom_logo( $blog_id );
}
```

Now my thought for a solution was the following: I change the way wordpress returns an image through *get_custom_logo()* (I'm prepared to code that in every time there's a WP update).

Here's the functions code:

```
function get_custom_logo( $blog_id = 0 ) {
$html = '';
$switched_blog = false;

if ( is_multisite() && ! empty( $blog_id ) && (int) $blog_id !== get_current_blog_id() ) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    $switched_blog = true;
}

$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );

// We have a logo. Logo is go.
if ( $custom_logo_id ) {
    $html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">%2$s</a>',
        esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),

        wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, 'full', false, array(
            'class'    => 'custom-logo',
            'itemprop' => 'logo',
        ) )
    );
}

// If no logo is set but we're in the Customizer, leave a placeholder (needed for the live preview).
elseif ( is_customize_preview() ) {
    $html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" style="display:none;"><img class="custom-logo"/></a>',
        esc_url( home_url( '/' ) )
    );
}

if ( $switched_blog ) {
    restore_current_blog();
}

return apply_filters( 'get_custom_logo', $html, $blog_id );
}
```

Am I wrong in thinking that if I change `$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );` to acquire a random image out of my logo folder that it's gonna work? And if I'm not wrong, can anybody help me with how to write that piece of code?

I apologise if this is a dumb question. Have a great week!